# How to loop and increase by 0.01 everytime?

Tags: c, loops

I'm really confused on this code.

Here's what I want it to do: Start with a "v" value of 5, carry out the rest of the functions/calculations, increase the "v" value by 0.01, carry out the functions/calculations, then increase the "v" value by 0.01 again, carry out the functions...do this 500 times or until a "v" value of 10.00 is reached, whichever is easier to code.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
//start loop over v  
for(iv=5;iv<=500;iv++) {  
    v=0.01*iv;
    //Lots and lots of calculations with v here
}
```

Here is what I get: I tried setting iv<=10 so it does 10 loops only just so I could test it first before leaving it on all night. It did only 6 loops, starting at v=0.05 and ending at 0.1. So the problem is that a) it didn't run for 10 loops, b) it didn't start at 5.00, it started at 0.05.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Holy crap, so many answers! I've tried 2 different answers so far, both work! I've been staring at this and changing code around for 3 hours, can't believe it was so easy.

Answer (score 7):

You need to start at `iv = 500`. and if you want 10 loops, and `iv++` is the update, then you stop before `510`.

Reason: `v = 0.01*iv`, so `v = 5` means `iv = 5/0.01 = 500`. As for the number of iterations, if your for loop is of the form `for (x = N; x < M; x++)` (constant `N` and `M`), then `max(0, M-N)` loops are executed, if `x` is not changed in the loop and no weird stuff (e.g. overflow, hidden casts of negative numbers to unsigned, etc.) occurs.

**EDIT**

Instead of using `v = 0.01 * iv`, `v = iv / 100.0` is probably more accurate. Reason: 0.01 is not exactly representable in floating point, but 100.0 is.

Comment: I think you're mistaken about the error of one multiplication being the same as a larger number of additions. With every addition, error accumulates because not just because 0.01 is not exactly representable, but also because the intermediate results are not exactly representable.

Comment: @janm: Yes. I was guilty of treating floating points as reals when attempting to think about it just now. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Changing SiegeX's code so it uses integers ("more accurate"):

```
double dv;
int iv;
for(iv = 500; dv <= 1000; iv += 1)
{
    dv = (double)iv / 100.0;
}
```

Comment: There isn't a need to cast `iv` to `double` - the constant `100.0` has type `double` so `iv` will be promoted by the usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: @caf I know, but just so Johnny gets that he'll need to use `(double)` with `iv` when he wants to change it to a `double`, and won't make any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
double iv;
for(iv = 5.0; iv <= 10.0 ; iv += 0.01) {
/* stuff here */
}
```

Comment: Operations with floating point numbers should be avoided whenever possible due to IEEE 754 inaccuracies.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
double v;
v = 5;
for (i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    v += 0.01;
    // Do Calculations Here.

    if (v >= 10.00) break;
}
```

This gives you both. This will iterate at most 500 times, but will break out of that loop if the v value reaches (or exceeds) 10.00.

If you wanted only one or the other:

The 10.00 Version:

```
double v;
v = 5.0;
while ( v < 10.00 )
{
    v += 0.01;
    // Do Calculations Here. 
}
```

The 500 iterations version:

```
double v;
int i;
v = 5.0;
for( i = 0; i < 500; i++ )
{
    v += 0.01;
    // Do Calculations.
}
```

(Note that this isn't C99, which allows for a cleaner declaration syntax in the loops).

Comment: I'm getting tired of saying this, but operations with floating point numbers should be avoided whenever possible due to IEEE 754 inaccuracies.

Comment: How do you propose incrementing a number by 0.01, then using that number in calculations without floating point operations? Especially with this being a homework problem, and unless it is in some numerical methods class (which it very much appears not to be) it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Perhaps instead of stating why all of the answers are wrong, you could provide the correct one.

Comment: Because the correct answer has already been given (though not by me).

Answer (score -1):

`iv <= 10` doesn't do it for 10 loops, it does it until `iv` is greater than 10.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. But it *does* a) explain the asker's observations, and b) not make the problem worse.

Answer (score -1):

```
//start loop over v  
for(iv=0;iv<500;iv++) //loop from 0 to 499
{  
    v=v+0.01; //increase v by 0.01
    //Lots and lots of calculations with v here
}
```

this should do it

Comment: Operations with floating point numbers should be avoided whenever possible due to IEEE 754 inaccuracies.